# The "o" notation and limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I just want some explanation about this notation ,it's very new to me ,and I've been also been given this exercise :
"Is this true or false : $x=o(\sqrt x)$ , $x\to 0$"
And it is true in the hint of the exercice ,and here is  the hint : $\lim_{x\to 0} $=$\frac{x}{\sqrt x}$=$0$ 
How do we get this expression $\frac{x}{\sqrt x}$ 
And what is the real meaning of this "o" notation?

Comment: "Is this true or false : $o(\sqrt x)$ , $x\to +\infty$" is not a statement, it is missing some part.

Comment: Thank you ,I edited it now

Comment: What do you mean "how do we get this expression"? That is the *definition* of "o" notation.

Comment: The definition of the "o" notation is what I don't get

Comment: Reference topic: Landau Little-o and Landau Big-O Notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $o(\ )$ notation : $f(x)=o(g(x))$ means $f(x)$ is negligible compared to $g(x)$.

Notice that the context is often implicit, I should say when "$x\to 0$" or "$x\to +\infty$" but that is generally stated in the question.

From now on, I will assume that we are studying in a neighbourhood of $0$.

Thus $f(x)=o(1)$ simply means $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} f(x)=0$.

This notation is multiplicative, i.e. $f(x)=o(1)\iff x^kf(x)=o(x^k)\iff f(x)g(x)=o(g(x))$

In particular (disregarding zeroes of $g$) then $f(x)=o(g(x))\iff \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=o(1)\to 0$

You can also see $f(x)=o(1)$ has $\forall \epsilon>0,\ |f(x)|<\epsilon$ in the epsilon-delta proofs, so you can see that the multiplicative property comes from $|f(x)g(x)|<\epsilon |g(x)|$

Regarding addition though it is "absorbant".

For instance if you have $f(x)=1+x^2+o(x)$, you can see that $x^2\ll x$ when $x$ is small, so we can simply ignore this term. and write $f(x)=1+o(x)$.

Similary when you add two quantities $f(x)=1+x+o(x^2)$ and $g(x)=3-7x+5x^2+x^3+o(x^3)$ the terms that are too small will be discarded:

$f(x)+g(x)=4-6x+5x^2+o(x^2)$

Comment: Similary when you add two quantities $f(x)=1+x+o(x^2)$ and $g(x)=3-7x+5x^2+x^3+o(x^3)$ the terms that are too small will be discarded:

$f(x)+g(x)=4-6x+5x^2+o(x^2)$

Comment: I don't understand this part

Comment: Basically $x^3+o(x^2)=o(x^2)$ because the term $x^3\ll x^2$ so it is discarded. It is as if you were measuring something with $\pm 1\text{ cm}$ precision, then adding $2\text{ mm}$ is useless, and you just discard it. This is the same principle.